# CSSHttpRequest - javascript does not work transferred

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I generate full html+css+javascript page, and paste it on other host via CSSHttpRequest.

But javascript not working on pasted page(http://learnit.by/test/).

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="csshttprequest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    CSSHttpRequest.get("irus.streetball.name/bsuir/encoded.css";, callback); 

    function callback(data) {
        document.getElementById('put_here').innerHTML = data;
    };
</script> 

<div id="put_here"></div>
```

Comment: can you post the code here please so people can see, only post the relevant code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can see a couple of syntax errors, whether they are whats causing your problems or not are another matter though, they may not be the only thing.

```
CSSHttpRequest.get("http://irus.streetball.name/bsuir/encoded.css", callback); 

function callback(data) {
    document.getElementById('put_here').innerHTML = data;
}
```

I have gotten rid of a semi colon after the url and one after the function.  You probably also need to add the http:// in as I have done.  The reason for this is that without it it will act as a relative url (or so I believe).

You could alternatley write the callback in anonymously, although this shouldnt make a difference as follows:

```
 CSSHttpRequest.get("http://irus.streetball.name/bsuir/encoded.css", function(data) {
    document.getElementById('put_here').innerHTML = data;
 });
```

Comment: The problem is not in the syntax. For some reason I put the wrong code in comments. As you can see this in the source's page: http://learnit.by/test/ - everything is fine. 

The page itself does not handle the javascript, but CSS and HTML work. First, I inserted the script as a reference, and it too did not work.

Here (http://irus.streetball.name/bsuir/run.php) you can view a page that generates an encoded css. And this page source: https://github.com/IRus/BSUIR-RTU/blob/master/run.php.

Comment: so your syntax is as I have? otherwise the syntax is wrong.  You have the http:// and you dont have the two semi colons?

Comment: ok so what have you done so far to try and debug? What is/isn't working?

Comment: In web developer error console i did not get any errors with javascript. All looks fine.

And I have no more ideas how to debug.

Comment: ok well instead of putting the data into the div in the callback function try just doing alert(data); and see if anything appears.

Comment: Hmm, I just see a lot of html, css and js code in the alert. All the code is inserted properly on the page, but your browser apparently does not want to execute javascript that is transmitted through csshttpreqest - maybe it's defense or anything else. I want to say that the code is inserted properly on the page, it can be viewed using Inspect. At the same html and css is displayed, and js is not working.

Comment: This is a security issue, you can not just insert scripts into your page and expect them to run, but I believe you can do something with `eval` to evaluate the string you put in as javascript.  I am not 100% certain on this though as I have never done it myself.

Comment: I read this forum http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=341532, and i think you right - it's impossible because this is security issue.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I dont think it's impossible but you can't just insert the code.  I believe you can eval the code though (the script) although as I said I'm not sure.

Comment: "but you can't just insert the code" - yes of course, it's working :)